# Google Apps Script: Creating a folder in Google Drive from a Google Form submission

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-workspace

I am trying to create a function which, upon the submission of a Google form, creates a folder in Google Drive using the first two fields of the form to name the folder. Currently the form is being created without issue, but no folder is created upon submission. Here's the function I've come up with based on some Googling which uses only the first field to create the folder name:

```
function createForm() {
 var form = FormApp.create('New Form');

var clientName = form.addTextItem();
 clientName.setTitle('Client Name');
var clientAddress = form.addTextItem();
 clientAddress.setTitle('Address');
var clientPhoneNumber = form.addTextItem();
 clientPhoneNumber.setTitle('Phone Number');

function createFolder(form) {
  var items = form.response.getItemResponses()
  var name = items[0].getResponse();
  DriveApp.createFolder(name);
}


}
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: is the script bounded to Google Form or is it standalone script?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge it's a standalone script.

Comment: createForm may actually create the form but What fills it in and submits the form?  createFolder needs to be in the onFormSubmit Trigger. And I think your going to have to attach it to the Form and not the spreadsheet.

Comment: The user fills in and submits the form, or at least that's what I'm trying to accomplish. The form creation seems to be working as I intend it to, but the folder creation isn't. I'll look into moving the createFolder into a trigger, thanks!

Comment: Do you have the drive app API turned on in the Apps script and turned on in the API console? If you wrap the drive app call in a try and catch you can see any errors if there any.

Comment: When a person completes a Form you want to create a new folder named as the first 2 fields. Then create a new Form inside that folder with the questions in the script??

Comment: @JamesDonnellan I want to create a new, empty folder in Drive upon submission of the form.

Answer (score 0):

As @Cooper suggests in the comments - there is nothing in your script that binds the createFolder function to the form and the form submission action. What you have to do is to separate the createFolder function from the createForm function and have the createForm function install a trigger to the created form that triggers the createFolder function on submission. See below example:

```
function createForm() {
 var form = FormApp.create('New Form');

var clientName = form.addTextItem();
 clientName.setTitle('Client Name');
var clientAddress = form.addTextItem();
 clientAddress.setTitle('Address');
var clientPhoneNumber = form.addTextItem();
 clientPhoneNumber.setTitle('Phone Number');
ScriptApp.newTrigger('createFolder').forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create();
}

function createFolder(form) {
  var items = form.response.getItemResponses()
  var name = items[0].getResponse();
  DriveApp.createFolder(name);
}
```