# Google Apps Script: Create Google Shared Drive Folder from a Google Form submission

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-workspace

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48292613/google-apps-script-creating-a-folder-in-google-drive-from-a-google-form-submiss) thread on creating a folder in Google Drive from a Google Form submission. Can any one help me on creating a folder but in **Google Shared Drives** instead from Google Form submission.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a new folder in the Shared Drive by modifying the following script,

```
function createFolder(form) {
  var items = form.response.getItemResponses()
  var name = items[0].getResponse();
  DriveApp.createFolder(name);
}
```

How about the following modification? In the current stage, fortunately, the folder ID is used, you can access the Shared Drive with [Drive service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive).

#### Modified script:

```
function createFolder(form) {
  var folderId = "###"; // Please set the folder ID on the Shared Drive. If you want to create a new folder to the root folder of the Shared Drive, please set the Drive ID here.

  var items = form.response.getItemResponses()
  var name = items[0].getResponse();
  DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFolder(name);
}
```

- In this modification, `folderId` is the folder ID of the specific folder in the Shared Drive or the Drive ID of the Shared Drive. When the Drive ID is used, the folder is created to the root folder of the Shared Drive.

#### Note:

- In this case, you are required to have permission for writing to the Shared Drive. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [getFolderById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid)

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, when I use your modified script and set the folderID on the Shared Drive and run it. The folder did not created in the folderID even-though the folder on the Shared Drive was created by me which I am the owner. any suggestions?

Comment: @WA666 Thank you for replying. When I tested my proposed script, I confirmed that a new folder can be created in the Shared Drive. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation of `when I use your modified script and set the folderID on the Shared Drive and run it. The folder did not created in the folderID even-though the folder on the Shared Drive was created by me which I am the owner.`. So can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your issue? By the way, an error occurs when you tested my proposed script?

Comment: @WA666 I think that Drive service can be used for the shared drive. But if in your situation, this cannot be used, how about using Drive API? In this case, please modify `DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFolder(name)` to `Drive.Files.insert({ parents: [{ id: folderId }], title: name, mimeType: MimeType.FOLDER }, null, {supportsAllDrives: true})` and test it again. At that time, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.

Comment: sorry, the script was working. I accidently left out 1 character in the folderID.(my bad) Another question, if I want to create the folder to the root folder of the Shared Drive it mentioned that I need set the Drive ID.  May I know where to obtain the Drive ID?

Comment: @WA666 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `May I know where to obtain the Drive ID?`, in this case, how about retrieving the URL of the Shared Drive? When you open the root folder of the Shared Drive, you can see the URL like `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/###`. In this case, the Drive ID is `###` of `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/###`.

Comment: @WA666 Or, as another method, you can see the Drive IDs of the Shared Drive that you have the permission using "Try this method" of "Drives: list" method of Drive API. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/list) When you click "EXECUTE" button on "Try this method", the metadata of your Shared Drives can be seen.

Comment: @WA666 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.